# Discord.js v14 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm new to discord.js and I'm currently working on a discord bot but I'm facing an issue with the **Events.InteractionCreate** callback. It seems to be a problem with the **get**, I also notice that there was no method for **commands** on this callback, Here is source of the error from my **index.js**.

```
const { token, clientId, guildId, ownerId } = require("./Config.json");
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, REST, Routes } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    ]
});

const commands = [];
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, "Utils");
const commandsFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandsFiles) {
    const command = require(`./Utils/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST().setToken(token);

async function Main() {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} Slash commands.`);

        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands }
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} Slash commands.`);

        client.login(token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

client.once(Events.ClientReady, (client) => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) { return; }

    // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    const command = interaction.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        return console.log(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});

Main();
```

And below is my **Utils/hi.js** code

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("hi")
        .setDescription("replies with Hello"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply({
            content: "Hello"
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping! :D

Comment: Interactions do not have a commands property, did you mean just `commands.get(...)`?

Comment: Or `interaction.guild.commands.get()`?

Comment: ``TypeError: interaction.guild.commands.get is not a function`` I tried both and still nothing works for me.

Comment: When iterating through `commandFiles` you will need to save each `command` to then access it's `execute()` function. Try initializing `client.commands = new Collection ()` then for each command of commandFiles do `client.commands.set(command.name, command)`, finally do `const command = client.commands.get(...)`